# Building a Social Network JavaScript, Bootstrap, JQuery, PHP and Mysqil

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysqli, social-networking

I am trying to build a social network that will be similar to Instagram.  Users will login, post, comment, like, share and send data to a server to be displayed or stored.  I would like to use JavaScript, JQuery, Bootstrap, PHP and Mysqil for database.

I am having a hard time understanding how all these technologies work together to build an application which will have millions of users at a time.

Can someone help with an overall understanding with examples so i can get a better vision in my head how i would take the best approach when i begin to build.

A step by step approach would help alot, thank you.

Comment: Pointless to enter into such a big project without solving the logic of the job. Not understandable that you want an example of how to do this. Search Big Data first.

Answer (score 0):

**First** I would recommend for you to learn the basics of all those languages you talked about.

**Second**, you should be ready to put a lot of effort on doing such stuff, as it won't be easy to nearly create one such as instagram, don't forget that they have a lot of employees.

**Third** - Now that we took all of that out of the way, let's go to the basics:

1. Make a responsive website using the bootstrap library, html, css and javascript.
2. Create a mysql database to save all of your users information.
3. Combine it with php to make dinamic stuff.

There's lots of tutorials on that, specially on https://www.udemy.com.

Check them out and Good Luck!!